# How to correctly use doctrine migrations with postressql

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I've got a **symfony 2.8** project with a **postgressql** database and the ID generation strategy is IDENTITY but every command I enter like

```
doctrine:schema:update
```

or

```
doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

return an error like this:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM "abstract_group_id_seq"':
> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "min_value" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM "abstract_group_id_seq"

Is it a schema name problem? Does anybody know how to setup doctrine properly? Thank you.

Comment: It's a really good question !

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using? Doctrine has some issues with PG10, see [this bug report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397435/how-to-correctly-use-doctrine-migrations-with-postressql)

Comment: yes, the postgres version is PG10

Answer (score 7):

If someone else still has this problem, make sure you are using the correct Postgres driver version in doctrine.yaml

[PostgreSQL DBAL](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3139)

Comment: Thank you for this helpful tip. Saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Change method _getPortableSequenceDefinition() located in file /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/PostgreSqlSchemaManager.php

to this one:

```
 protected function _getPortableSequenceDefinition($sequence)
    {
        if ($sequence['schemaname'] != 'public') {
            $sequenceName = $sequence['schemaname'] . "." . $sequence['relname'];
        } else {
            $sequenceName = $sequence['relname'];
        }

        $version = floatval($this->_conn->getWrappedConnection()->getServerVersion());

        if ($version >= 10) {$data = $this->_conn->fetchAll('SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM pg_sequences WHERE schemaname = \'public\' AND sequencename = '.$this->_conn->quote($sequenceName));
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $this->_conn->fetchAll('SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM ' . $this->_platform->quoteIdentifier($sequenceName));
        }

        return new Sequence($sequenceName, $data[0]['increment_by'], $data[0]['min_value']);
    }
```